# Splitar string em C

Tags: c, array, string

sou bem iniciante em C ainda, mas tenho bastante experiencia com python, estou com um projeto que preciso receber do usuario 3 numeros na mesma linha e fazer um vetor com esses 3 numeros

na entrada digito

3 1 37

queria que formasse um vetor [3,1,37]
só tem uma coisa, o primeiro(nesse caso o 3) também pode ser caracteres.
algo como

load 1 23
ou
delete 2 56

em python seria extremamente simples, era só receber uma string entrada e dps fazer um entrada=entrada.split()

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>C
int main ()
{
  char entrada[31];
  char * separado;
  gets(entrada);
  separado = strtok (entrada," ");
  while (separado != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",separado);
    separado = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

achei esse codigo num forum gringo, alguem sabe se tem maneira mais simples ou então me explicar como funciona? não entendi

Comment: Pertinente a sua pergunta, porem voce nao quer __splitar__ (do verbo split em ingles que significar dividir, separar) voce precisa **concatenar** dados, ou seja, juntar 3 dados passados pelo usuario separados por virgula em um array.

Comment: mas seria tipo dividir 1 string em 3

Comment: Entendi, mas de onde o usuario vai passar esses numeros, qual a origem desses 3 numeros? Vem direto do terminal? Se sao 3 numeros (3 dados distintos) é necessario um separador certo?

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo capaz de converter uma string contendo dados separados por espaco e aramazena-los em um vetor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char ** strsplit( const char * src, const char * delim )
{
    char * pbuf = NULL;
    char * ptok = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int srclen = 0;
    char ** pparr = NULL;

    srclen = strlen( src );

    pbuf = (char*) malloc( srclen + 1 );

    if( !pbuf )
        return NULL;

    strcpy( pbuf, src );

    ptok = strtok( pbuf, delim );

    while( ptok )
    {
        pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
        *(pparr + count) = strdup(ptok);

        count++;
        ptok = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }

    pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
    *(pparr + count) = NULL;

    free(pbuf);

    return pparr;
}


void strsplitfree( char ** strlist )
{
    int i = 0;

    while( strlist[i])
        free( strlist[i++] );

    free( strlist );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    char ** vec = NULL;

    vec = strsplit( "3 pratos de trigo para 3 tigres tristes", " " );

    while( vec[i] )
    {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", i , vec[i] );
        i++;
    }

    strsplitfree( vec );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./teste 
[0] 3
[1] pratos
[2] de
[3] trigo
[4] para
[5] 3
[6] tigres
[7] tristes
```